# What real-life Destroyer is Civ 5's modeled after?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Unlike some units, the civlopedia doesn't mention what real-life ship class the Destroyer unit is based off of. My best (amateur) guess is that it's an American or British design, possibly the American [Sims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sims-class_destroyer), [Fletcher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher-class_destroyer), or [Benson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benson-class_destroyer) classes, or the British [U and V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_and_V-class_destroyer), [W and Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z-class_destroyer), or [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-class_destroyer) classes. However, at this size and resolution it could also pass as some German or Japanese designs; there seemed to be some level of international similarities.

Most of the real-life ships seem to have rear guns, which the in-game model doesn't. This could be a simplicity/speed/laziness decision on by developers, or it could help narrow it down further.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, if you look [here](http://well-of-souls.com/civ/civ5_modern_units.html) the in-game destroyer does have rear guns.

Looking over some of your suggested American designs, I noticed the numbering scheme used and searched Wikipedia for DD-443 (the number on the hull of the destroyer's icon), and came up with the [Gleaves-class destroyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleaves_class_destroyer) (specifically the [USS Swanson](https://www.google.ca/search?q=USS+Swanson+%28DD-443%29&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X))

[image: Left image courtesy of well-of-souls.com, right image from modelshipgallery.com]

Personally, I think they look rather close enough to call it a match.

Comment: Good call on the bow numbering; that was how I initially pegged it as US make.